# What is the name for the relationship between two elements in the same group?

Tags: terminology, periodic-table

I'm looking for a specific term which can be used to describe two elements in the same group of the Periodic Table. This would be useful since elements in the same group tend to have similar chemical/physical properties.

For example, is there a word that could fill in the blank: *"X is a _______ of Y"*, where X and Y are in the same group? It has to be something that is generalisable to all groups, not just one particular group, so terms like "alkali metals" or "halogens" are too specific.

Comment: The correct (but infrequently used) term is 'congener', https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congener_(chemistry)#Other

Comment: The term you are looking for is "[congener][1]". Quoting the Wikipedia:

> Congeners can refer to other elements in the same group in the periodic table. For example, congeners of the Group 11 element copper are silver and gold, sometimes found together in the same ores (porphyry copper deposit) due to their chemical similarity.

or as described in the IUPAC [Gold Book][2]:

> One of two or more substances related to each other by origin, structure, or function.


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congener_(chemistry)
  [2]: https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/CT06819

Comment: Note that congener doesn't only mean "two elements in the same group".  It also refers to minor chemical components in a mixture that give it distinctive characteristics (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congener_(beverages) ), and is used in biology to refer to species in the same genus (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congener).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct term is congener. Congeners refer to elements in the same group in periodic table.

For example, congeners of the Group 1 elements are Li , Na and K etc.

Therefore , X is a congener of Y is the right statement.